# What is the boundary of a plane excluding a line.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

```
f(x,y) = y/x^2
```

Here, we can see that the x = 0 is not in the function domain, so what should be the domain's boundary?

Comment: That's it: the boundary of the domain of $f$ is the line $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\,x=0\}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)

Comment: Your title makes no sense — you mean *the plane*, not *real numbers*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary is the entire line $x=0$, since any ball centred on the line will always contain both points inside and outside the domain.